# How to override PHP attributes in a custom drush command?

Tags: drush

I have a custom drush command that is providing table output. Per the docs, since the command will be for Drupal 10+, I'm using PHP attributes. Specifically, there is this attribute:

```
#[CLI\FieldLabels(labels:
```

But in my case, the labels need to change based on some dynamic factors, as will

```
#[CLI\DefaultTableFields(fields:
```

Is there a way to either provide the label and field information in a non-static way to begin with, or to override it?

I did note the CommandInfoAlterer discussion, but wasn't sure whether this ran once at the start or whether I could add additional methods to it and call them dynamically to accomplish my goals.